# batch file regex to get specific number from filename

Tags: regex, batch-file

I have a file name

`pp-sssss-iiii-12.0.111.22_31-i-P.0.16.1.1`

I want from the name only this (output desired):

`12.0.111.22_31`

then replace `.` with `0` and remove '_' so I got the below

`1200011102231`

well I tried to start from something like this

```
cd %cd% 
for %%F in (*.txt) do echo %%~nxF >>1.txt
```

but I didnt know how to continue

edit , the code :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\moudiz\Desktop\new folder\tttt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pbd" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=4delims=-" %%d IN ("%%a") DO (
  SET "modname=%%d"
  SET "modname=!modname:.=0!"
  SET "modname=!modname:_=!"
  ECHO %%a becomes !modname!
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
pause
```

the name of the file

`P-Script-LogFiles-1.0.33.33_123-IB-P.0.16.357.1.pbd`

the output `100033033123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[note: OP belatedly asked for the first token of the name to be prepended to the name generated from the original post, hence use of `%%c` below]

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (

 echo File "%%a"

 FOR /f "tokens=1,4delims=-" %%c IN ("%%a") DO (
  SET "modname=%%d"
  SET "modname=!modname:.=0!"
  SET "modname=!modname:_=!"
  ECHO %%a becomes %%c!modname!
 )
 pause
)

pause

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Using `delayedexpansion`, !var! refers to the modified value of the variable and `set "var=!var:string=gnirts!" substitutes "gnirts" for "string" in`var`and assigns the result back to`var`.

Now - quite what you want to do with this modified result, you don't reveal - but guessing at renaming,

```
echo ren "%%a" "!modname!"
```

should be usable

To prepend the first token, simply change the `tokens=` to `1,4` *to select the first and fourth tokens) - and change the `metavariable` in the `for` to `%%c` (in order that the `%%d` processing remains the same), then use `%%c` which will contain the portion of the original filename before the first `-`.

Comment: I want the result to be on a file >> result.txt .. I copied your example , I modefied this  `'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.pbd" '` , added `pause` and i ran it but it didnt work

Comment: Sorry - "it didn't work" doesn't provide many clues. Using the filename that you nominate, `pp-sssss-iiii-12.0.111.22_31-i-P.0.16.1.1.txt` (I added the `.txt` since your posted code uses a `*.txt` mask), this routine `echo`ed "pp-sssss-iiii-12.0.111.22_31-i-P.0.16.1.1.txt becomes 1200011102231" which is what you appeared to want. I've no idea where `*.pbd` comes into the picture.

Comment: the `.pbd` was related to the scenario I was doing. ill post in the edit how I copied your code , and the exact name of the file okay?

Comment: You start by saying "file" and your edit says "folder". If you want the name of a directory, then change the `dir` command from `/a-d` (meaning "attributes - no directories) to `/ad` (meaning "attributes - directories only)

Comment: typo mistake , `file` but i didnt understand why I want to change to /ad ? i run the below code and it didnt work , the `cmd` is not pausing

Comment: `/a-d` will list files. `/ad` will list directories. You've changed your text to now say `file` so the `/a-d` is correct. Now we need to tackle the name of the actual file. Originally, you stated you were using `*.txt` - which means "all files that end `.txt` - which means a file named precisely `P-Script-LogFiles-1.0.33.33_123-IB-P.0.16.357.1` would not be processed since it doesn't end `.txt`. You've then modified this to `*.pbd` - which means that to pass the selection mask, the filename must end `.pbd`. If you have a filename ending `.1` then you need a mask of `*.1` not `*.pbd`.

Comment: its a file named `P-Script-LogFiles-1.0.33.33_123-IB-P.0.16.357.1.pbd` when I run the above code , the cmd doesnt pause i just finish quickly , it seems there is an error , I am not familiar with batch file thats why i am seeking your help

Comment: I've modified the code to add `pause` statements at appropriate points and also to display the name of the file being processed. The first `pause` will pause on each filename found and the second will pause before terminating the process. you could also add `ECHO modname=!modname!` after each line which sets `modname` to see what values are being assigned. As I said, it works for me, and I can't see over your shoulder, so you need to be both precise and expansive in your report.

Comment: Superb , it worked , i forget to mention something ,if you want I can add it as another question, I want to add the first part in name for example: in your code I ma getting the number `100033033123` I want to add the first word before `-' which is `p` so the output would be p100033033123 , If the file name is `PPPP-Script-LogFiles-1.0.33.33_123-IB-P.0.16.357.1.pbd` I want it to be `ppp100033033123` if you want as another question i would post it